# Какая программа сможет по коду С++ построить диаграмму UML?

Tags: uml

У меня есть код и мне нужно найти программу, которая построит диаграмму, потому что этого требует метод обратного проектирования.
заранее спасибо!

Comment: Enterprise Architect вроде умеет, ну и традиционно Rational.

Но ваш вопрос, конечно, оффтопик.

Comment: Возможно Poseidon от gentleware.com, но это из той области, где  мои знания минимальны (или чуть меньше). Просто раньше попадалась ссылка.

Comment: благодарна!
попробую